# What this Declaration meant in C

Tags: c, struct, structure

I have a structure in C and at end have some  declration which not able to decode

```
struct Student
{
   int roll;
   char name;
   int age;
};

extern struct Student dev[];
```

what does last statement mean in C??

Comment: Um, don't you have a book on C or a C reference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
extern struct Student dev[];
```

Tells the compiler that `dev` is an array of the type `struct Student` and it is defined somewhere else(other translation unit).

Comment: So youe mean to say every member of dev is of type struct Student

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: Yes, `dev` is an array. And each element of this array is of the type `Student`.

Comment: IS ther any usecase you like to mention here of it.

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: What usecase?

Comment: where declaring this dev would be useful?

Comment: In one of the scenrio struct Student *ptr=dev has been done but not sure what they are doing

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar: When you want to create a global array which is shared among multiple files.

Answer (score 2):

It means that `dev[]` is not declared in this C/object file, but in another. You'll have to link that other object to your binary to be able to use that variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
        struct students
    {
    int num;
    char name[100];
    char dept[100];
   } extern struct students student[];
```

student[] is the structure array.its used for the access the structure members
  like num,name,dept.

int   j=100;

```
             #include<stdio.h>

                   main(){

                  for(i=0;i<j;i++)
                         {
                               scanf("%d",&student[i].num);
                               scanf("%s",student[i].name);
                               scanf("%s",student[i].dept);
                           }


                        for(i=0;i<j;i++)
                            {
                                  printf("%d\n",student[i].num);
                                  printf("%s\n",student[i].name);
                                   printf("%s\n",student[i].dept);
     }
     }
```

It is used to the access the 100 records of members of the structure